# How can you last hit competently with Ryze?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just bought Ryze and am having such a hard time farming early with Ryze with auto attacks.  I have even specced into minion damage masteries and am always still way lower in CS than many of my other AP Champions. What can I do to improve my last hitting with him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been playing champions in mid lane that have horrific auto-attack animations and/or low base AD/AD-scaling for as long as I can remember (see: LB, Anivia, Ryze).

From what I've noticed, Ryze's auto-attack much resembles that of a Tower or a Siege Minion in the sense that the damage is done slightly **after** the bolt of lightning(?) appears to hit your target.

Just keep trying to last hit, but adjust your timing ever so slightly to compensate for this discrepancy.  It'll take a bit of time adjusting when you switch mids between games, but eventually the transition will be seamless.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem playing Anivia,the animation was slower or at least in my mind that it would always throw me off and my cs would be horrible until getting blue when i would be able to just spam r... I know its probably not the type of answer you were expecting but it just comes down to playing him more and practicing until it just feels like any normal animation to you , that's what i did at least : )

Answer (score 1):

Just like with any champion, go into a 1v1 bot match, and practice last hitting. It's the best way to get the feel of the champions auto attack. Professional players still do it.

Answer (score 0):

Needs more knowledge of player itself and their own ability to CS.  How are they choosing to last hit if at all.  Many new players just auto-attack a lane blindly, and if you are one, I would agree that you will have a hard time farming with any champ that doesn't have very high attack speed or attack damage.

Comment: That's not the case, Ryze is the only champion I miss 1 or so creeps a wave.  There is something weird with his animation I can't get it.  No I do not autoattack creeps unless they are pushing to hard towards the tower.

Comment: Sorry, but I honestly don't think it's the champion but the player.  I see many streamers and players play Ryze and have no problems getting CS, using their abilities only to harass.  As an AP carry, he would tend to have a rather low attack speed and low base AD, so last hitting will be a challenge.  But once you practice, you should be able to work through it.  For practice, play custom games or go against bots and just practice last hitting with Ryze (or insert any other champ you have trouble last hitting with here)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it's something that comes with practice, but starting with a mekki pendant lets you last hit with Q a lot more comfortably, Ryze's spell damage is very low in the first few levels anyway, if you can manage to get an early back for tear + boots you'll be set by then.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get better at last hitting on a specific champion is through practice. Taking the flat attack damage and minion damage masteries can simplify this process. Also harassing your opponent will alleviate pressure when you go to last hit. You should judge when to harass by the health of your minions. For Ryze specifically, When your opponent comes in to CS quickly harass them or even combo them to alleviate pressure and make your last hitting more manageable.